# plaid connect to client with node error

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, plaid

I'm using node backend and am trying to connect to plaid. 
My code:

```
var plaid = require('plaid');

var clientID = "bla";
var secretID = "bla";
var publicKey = "bla";

var client = new plaid.Client(
    clientID,
    secretID,
    publicKey,
    plaid.environments.sandbox

);
```

However I am getting this error in my console:

```
    throw new Error('Invalid Plaid environment');
    ^

Error: Invalid Plaid environment
    at new Plaid.Client (C:\Users\me\Documents\found\SPA\node_modules\plaid\index.js:26:11)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\me\Documents\found\SPA\app\routes.js:48:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\Documents\found\SPA\server.js:48:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
```

I have tried using each of these with no luck:

```
plaid.environments.sandbox
plaid.environments.development 
plaid.environments.tartan
```

What's going on?

Ref: https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/#accessing-item-data

UPDATE:
I've gotten this code below to work in another part of my app:

```
var plaidClient = new plaid.Client(clientID, secretID, plaid.environments.tartan);
```

However I am trying to use `client.getTransactions()` and it is required to have `var plaidClient = new plaid.Client(clientID, secretID, publicID, plaid.environments.sandbox);`
in order for `client.getTransactions()` to work.

UPDATE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I had the wrong version of plaid installed. I needed to uninstall and reinstall to fix. Works now.